# Solve the word game Ghost (as seen on xkcd) - spelling letters without making a word

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, puzzle

How can one solve the word game Ghost? [Ghost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_(game)) is a two player word game. Players take turns adding letters to a growing word fragment.

Quoting [Randall Munroe](http://blog.xkcd.com/2007/12/31/ghost/)

> To play Ghost, you alternate saying letters. The first person to either (a) spell a word, or (b) create a string that cannot be the start of a word, loses. So you alternate building a word, and you have to always be working toward a word, but you can’t be the one to end it. Sample games, with players one and two alternating letters:
>
> G-A-M-E — Player 1 loses by spelling “Game”
>
> A-B-S-O-R-B — Player 2 loses by spelling “ABSORB”
>
> B-Z-”Challenge” — Player 1, seeing “Z”, says “Challenge.” meaning “I think you’re not building toward a word. Name a word that starts with ‘BZ’ and prove you’re not just making stuff up.” Player 2 can’t, and loses. If he could, he’d win.

Munroe then blags that he solved the game (against a particular dictionary) on a flight. He

- asserts the first player can always win
- exhibits a short crib sheet the first player can use to gaurantee a win
- exhibits a short crib sheet the second player can use to win if the first player errs

For example, if the first player opens with 'L', the second player can reply with another 'L', forcing the first player to lose at 'LLAMA'.

Munroe didn't share his algorithm or his code :( How did he solve Ghost?

---

There's also a [harder variant](http://everything2.com/user/%252Fdev%252Fjoe/writeups/Ghost) where letters can be prepended to the word fragment.

Comment: It's a [Combinatorial Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory) in which the [Minimax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) tree resembles the [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for the dictionary on which the game is played.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve for a dictionary--

You create a tree structure where the root node is no letters, and each child node is the result of adding the next letter in a word to a tree.

The leaf nodes are complete words (you can throw away words that have an initial subset that is also a complete word).

When you've built the complete tree and have all the leaf nodes, the leaf nodes with an odd-number of letters are goals for player two and the nodes with an even number of letters are goals for player 1.

You go up a level; if all the nodes beneath a given node are goals for player x, that node also becomes a goal for player x; or if any of the nodes beneath a given node are goals for player x, and the node will be hit on player x's turn, that node becomes a goal for player x.

If a single character node is a goal for player 1, player 1 can always win the game.

Answer (score 1):

Build a tree (trie) from all the words in the dictionary.

We will step-by-step mark all the nodes in the tree as winners for either player 1 or 2.

- In the leaves you already know the result of the game, so simply mark
  them
- Once all the children of a leave are filled we know the result:
  if there is at least one winner child leaf for the player who is
  making the next move, then the parent leaf in question is winner for
  him, otherwise for the other player.
- With a post-order traversal of the tree following these two steps we can fill all the tree, and decide that at each node what is the winning step for each player.

Check the root node (with the empty word) to see who has a winning strategy (assuming that the other player plays perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I did the first part a year ago, but today I thought about how to prune to a concise winning strategy

https://github.com/hickford/ghost